# why REPLY variable in read builtin skip white space?

Tags: bash, read

```
echo "     a" | while read; do echo "$REPLY"; done
```

will output ".....a" which contains leading white space. However,

```
echo "     a" | while read line; do echo "$line"; done
```

will output "a" with leading white space skipped (OK, because word splitting).

It seems the REPLY variable has the same effect of IFS set to null:

```
echo "     a" | while IFS= read line; do echo "$line"; done
```

From the bash manual, I can't find the reason. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `read` [man page](https://ss64.com/bash/read.html):

> Read one line from the standard input, (or from a file) and assign the **word(s)** to variable name(s).
>
> If no names are supplied, **the line** read is assigned to the variable **REPLY**.

So, `$REPLY` is always the whole **line**, while the assigned variables are always **words**. It would not work otherwise e.g. if you have multiple words, what would `$REPLY` be?

Comment: OK, so a line is read, the word split is not perform yet.